# Atualizar automaticamente vídeo postado no youtube

Tags: youtube

Tenho um canal no youtube e quero que toda vez que coloco vídeo novo, atualize automaticamente no iframe do meu blog.

Comment: Pegue o feed do seu canal e escreva um script para atualizá-lo no período em que você geralmente posta seus vídeos.

Comment: Você já tentou alguma coisa? Tem alguma dificuldade *específica* que os recursos do seu blog não provêem?

Comment: Então galera, na verdade não é um blog e sim um site. supermercadotosta.com.br e toda semana tem promoção, e toda vez tenho que mudar o src hardcode mesmo. Então gostaria de automatizar essa vinculação. Ainda não tenho script, só o iframe mesmo e mudo do source.

Comment: Seria melhor se fosse fornecesse mais detalhes sobre como quer fazer isso. Backend ou frontend? Você tem acesso à API do YouTube? De qualquer forma, um truque que eu vi é postar todos os seus vídeos numa única playlist, e fazer embed da playlist no site, dessa forma o vídeo mais novo sempre vai ser mostrado. É simples e funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa o parâmetro `listType=user_uploads` que o iframe vai mostrar todos os posts recentes do seu canal.

Aqui está um exemplo que usei no meu site (http://holiveira.com)

```
<iframe 
width="560" height="315" 
src="//www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=metacodigo&showinfo=1&theme=light" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

É só trocar o valor "metacodigo" do parâmetro list pelo nome do seu canal.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Muito Obrigada holiveira, deu certo. Era isso que eu precisava. Abraços.